# How to send messages to IBM MQ using SOAPUI

Tags: groovy, jms, soapui, ibm-mq, hermes-jms

I am able to send messages to ActiveMQ using SOAPUI groovy script.

I followed the configuration from the link

https://www.soapui.org/documentation/jms/config.html &

https://www.soapui.org/jms/working-with-jms-messages.html

I could send message to Apache ActivMQ.

Now I want to use IBM MQ instead of ActivMQ.

1) Could you please let me know what are the changes with respect to configuration that I need to make for IBM MQ?

2) The working Groovy script for ActiveMQ will work with IBM MQ as well? Or i need to modify Groovy Script?

3) Could you please provide me link for sending JMS message to IBMMQ using SOAPUI?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This ( https://www.soapui.org/documentation/jms/config.html ) seems like it should work with WebSphere MQ as well, just make sure you have the correct JAR files added and set the correct properties: hostname, port, channel.

Comment: You need to configure it first. Have you checked this link to configure? http://ewaldertl.blogspot.in/2013/08/how-to-connect-to-websphere-mq-server.html

Answer (score 1):

THis may not directly answer your questions, but depending of your use case, you could check [JMSToolBox](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmstoolbox/?source=directory) . It's a tool that allows to automate putting message to Q Managers including IBM MQ and Apache Active MQ